# Drag and drop with modifiers in wxpython

Tags: drag-and-drop, wxpython

Is there a way to capture modifiers during a drag-and-drop in wxpython? It is mentioned in a couple of posts as a sidenote ([The OLE way of doing drag&drop in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476142/the-ole-way-of-doing-dragdrop-in-wxpython), [wx.TreeCtrl drag and drop, copy and move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803386/wx-treectrl-drag-and-drop-copy-and-move)), but neither of those mentions how to catch these modifiers.

I am aware of CmdDown(), but that requires an EVT_CHAR. Is there a way to force an EVT_CHAR during a drag and drop (to a canvas)?

At the end of the day, I could use some global hook, but I know there are equivalents in similar packages that allow you to catch modifiers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was using GetMouseState() which has booleans for modifiers packed into it. I had been trying to use GetKeyState(), but I needed to pass in a key code. In retrospect, I think I could've passed in any key and then just checked for modifiers since that's what I actually want. Anyhow - it works now.

```
def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
    mouse = wx.GetMouseState()
    if mouse.CmdDown():
        self.frame.paths += filenames
    else:
        self.frame.paths = filenames
    self.frame.draw_figure()
```